Adding space after chevron (>) in PowerShell
My prompt in PowerShell looks like this:
PS>dir

I have changed the prompt to not display a path, by changing the profile file.
I want to include a space after the >.
How to do that?
I have tried adding a space after the display text in the profile file.
function prompt{
    $p = -path
    "$p> "
}

I was hoping the space after p> would do the trick but it does not. Neither does adding \t.

If you want to display just "PS> " you could just use:
function prompt {"PS> "}

If you only want to display the current folder without the full path, then this would be the better option:
function prompt {
    $p = Split-Path -Path (Get-Location) -Leaf
    "$p> "
}


Jakobb's helpful answer provides an effective solution.
As for what you tried:

$p = -path causes a (statement-)terminating error (PowerShell looks for an executable with verbatim name -path, and fails).

When a terminating error (whether statement-terminating or script-terminating, such as generated with throw) occurs in a custom prompt function, PowerShell falls back to its built-in default prompt, which is PS> (i.e. with no space following >) - this is what you saw.

By contrast, if a non-terminating error occurs inside a prompt function (e.g., Get-Item NoSuchFile), PowerShell quietly ignores it.



The upshot is:

If you have a custom prompt function in place, but the prompt unexpectedly renders as PS>, the implication is that:

Either: An unhandled terminating error has occurred during execution of your custom function
Or: Your custom function produces no (success-stream) output or outputs the empty string.[1]


To troubleshoot your custom function, invoke it directly (prompt or & prompt), in which case any errors will surface.

If there's a chance that a terminating error can legitimately occur in your custom function (which seems unlikely), handle it with a try { ... } catch { ... } statement and make sure that your function always produces success-stream output.



[1] If you write to other output streams except the error stream, e.g., via Write-Host, that output does print, but in addition to (before) the built-in prompt, PS>.
